# I need to intercept the logout event and execute a redirection before close the session

Tags: magento2

Right now I implemented an observer of the logout event and Im able to execute a redirection using the header('Location: ...') + exit  solution, but this is not accepted by Magento2 since that breaks the normal flow.

I want to execute a redirection trying to get the control of the request and setting the URL.. but Im not able to do it.

An alternative is to create a plugin that gonna be able to control all the logout event stuff, but I dont know how to do that.

Here is a previous try:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106972/magento2-custom-logout-observer-with-redirection

Any one can share a way to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for controller override.
Just override and do whatever you want.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68793/magento-2-rewrite-controller